# Facebook application : Doesn't redirect to OAuth in an iFrame

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, oauth

I am currently developing a facebook application using the php sdk and the js sdk. (I need both of them)

When a user has not yet authorized the application and loads the canvas page (https://apps.facebook.com/app_name/), nothing happens, he just gets a blank page  with the facebook bar on top.
But if he loads the direct url of the application (https://my_app.mydomain.com), it works fine and he is redirected to the OAuth Dialog. If he authorizes the application, he is then redirected to https://apps.facebook.com/app_name/ and the iframe loads correctly.

If the user has already authorized the applications, both links are working (https://apps.facebook.com/app_name/ and https://my_app.mydomain.com).

Here is my authentication code :

```
<?php

require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '327991330620101',
  'secret' => '79asecretcc4300',
  'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();



if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {

    $params = array(
      'scope' => 'publish_stream',
      'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/quiet_quies/'
    );

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
  header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea about this ? It's really driving me mad...
Thanks for you help.

Comment: You __can not__ load the auth dialog into any kind of (i)frame. Use JavaScript to break out of it for login (script element with `top.location.href = {login_url}`), or use client-side login instead, using the JS SDK.

Comment: But if the user has not authorized the application, my page isn't loaded at all, so I cannot put any js in it...

Comment: Of course your app gets loaded anyway – but it depends on what you do in this case, if things go well or not. If you are still using header as shown in your script, then only the page with just the FB logo gets loaded into the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, @CBroe is right, in your `php` code try replacing `header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);` line with

```
echo "<script language=javascript>top.location.href ='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
```

it should work then.